# How can I dynamically scale Widgets(cards, in my case) in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

My app is a listview full of cards full of things. I want one of the cards to be clickable and that this card grows by 100% if someone clicks it.

The card i want to grow has a Card and a horizontal scrollable list view full of images.

```dart
Transform.scale(
    scale: 2,
    child: ImageCard(_movie)
),
```

What I tried first was using a Transform.scale, but this made the Card disappear when i srolled too far up or down, and it layed over the cards above and below the cards beneath it. I am first trying to find a way to scale up a card, and will then try to do it dynamically.

Is there a (easy) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [AnimatedContainer](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container). Put your card as a child and then change width and height according to your needs.

Comment: i will try it tomorrow and then tell ya how it went, thank you!